# Create s3 endpoint to a different region than current one

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I have an account in region ca-central. I wish to make call to a Public S3 bucket located in us-east.
As much as possible, these call have to be make through https (I am actually using apt-get), but if not possible I can try to use CLI call to download my data.

I can not exit public network due to firewall limitations, I need to stay internal to AWS network.
Can I do it through a S3 endpoint? The only endpoint I can create are connected to my current region (so ca-central). Or the only way is to do it through public network?

Comment: Did my answer work for you?

Comment: Sorry, did not had the chance to test this till now. 
It does not work, the firewall still block the access stating it goes outside. I do not know if it is because the firewall is too zelous and does not understand the it stays inside, or if it is because it actually goes outside. Still in investigation

Answer (score 0):

Yes, regardless of which region the bucket lives in, you will be able to reach it via AWS private link with either a VPC interface or gateway endpoint deployed correctly in the region you're working in.

Comment: Thanks, but how do I do this? When I try to add VPC endpoint to S3, only endpoint to my region are available.

Comment: @Djoby that's what I said. Deploy the endpoint to your region